# Laravel / Moment - How to determine if created_at during Daylight Savings?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, momentjs, dst

How do I determine if an entry in my database (`laravel`) was stored during Daylight Savings time using the `created_at` field?

I'm trying to calculate the time **difference between when a record was saved and now** so I can do can show something like `3 hours ago` or `49 minutes ago`. This was working fine, until the UK entered Daylight Savings Time a couple of weeks ago and now all times are inflated by 1 Hour.

I'm using moment to show the result like the following;

```
getElapsedString(from) {
   return moment(from).fromNow();
}
```

The data is stored in my database in the following format and this is what is passed in to the above function as `from`;

`2019-04-10 09:27:48`

I'm not doing anything to the dates when they are stored. This is handled by Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Inside config/app.php there is a

```
'timezone' => ''
```

you can set it to:

```
'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
```

It will set the default timezone and save created_at with this timezone with current daylight

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I'm aware though, this will only work for new entries going forward. It won't update entries already in the database.

Comment: i'm afraid it won't work, because it doesn't know in which timezone you entered this timestamp. in the future you can use 
    $table->dateTimeTz('created_at'); 
to save with timezone